# Extracting substrings from a block of text in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, text-files, substring

```
INSERT INTO Pax.SalesDocumentCoupon VALUES ('67c4158a-5d9f-4302-aaba-8fcddc0af552','3','TZX','SAW','','','EAOW','','00137','07-May-2013 12:00:00 AM','','','','E','','','','','','','','624','07-May-2013 12:00:00 AM','00137','TZX','SAW','Y','','F','N','False','X','fc12d5b5-c677-4207-81f4-5207a4f0705d','2481624807','6242481624807')
Filename : C:\Users\Relate 18\Desktop\PC DATA FILES\SAC\SAC0805201301_00002.txt
Table Name : Pax.SalesDocumentCoupon
Sql Stmt  :  INSERT INTO Pax.SalesDocumentCoupon VALUES ('67c4158a-5d9f-4302-aaba-8fcddc0af552','3','TZX','SAW','','','EAOW','','00137','07-May-2013 12:00:00 AM','','','','E','','','','','','','','624','07-May-2013 12:00:00 AM','00137','TZX','SAW','Y','','F','N','False','X','fc12d5b5-c677-4207-81f4-5207a4f0705d','2481624807','6242481624807')
Error Msg : Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_SalesDocumentCoupon'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'Pax.SalesDocumentCoupon'. The duplicate key value is (67c4158a-5d9f-4302-aaba-8fcddc0af552, 3).
The statement has been terminated.

 INSERT INTO Pax.SalesDocumentCoupon VALUES ('67c4158a-5d9f-4302-aaba-8fcddc0af552','4','SAW','BRU','','','GNBAGT','','00801','07-May-2013 12:00:00 AM','','','','G','','','','','','','','624','07-May-2013 12:00:00 AM','00801','SAW','BRU','Y','','F','N','False','X','f05365cd-9570-4b1c-b109-6ace5eaf1ea5','2481624807','6242481624807')
Filename : C:\Users\Relate 18\Desktop\PC DATA FILES\SAC\SAC0805201301_00002.txt
Table Name : Pax.SalesDocumentCoupon
Sql Stmt  :  INSERT INTO Pax.SalesDocumentCoupon VALUES ('67c4158a-5d9f-4302-aaba-8fcddc0af552','4','SAW','BRU','','','GNBAGT','','00801','07-May-2013 12:00:00 AM','','','','G','','','','','','','','624','07-May-2013 12:00:00 AM','00801','SAW','BRU','Y','','F','N','False','X','f05365cd-9570-4b1c-b109-6ace5eaf1ea5','2481624807','6242481624807')
Error Msg : Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_SalesDocumentCoupon'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'Pax.SalesDocumentCoupon'. The duplicate key value is (67c4158a-5d9f-4302-aaba-8fcddc0af552, 4).
The statement has been terminated.
```

I have the above file(there are more blocks i showed only 2 as the others too are alike)
I need to extract the SQL statement along with the the attached error message.

Till now i tried the codes below

```
        while ((sql_line = SR.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            string RequiredLine1 = "Sql Stmt";
            //sql_line = SR.ReadLine();
            if (sql_line.Contains(RequiredLine1))
            {
                //crop out string that comes before:
                int index = sql_line.IndexOf(":") + 1;
                sql_line = sql_line.Substring(index);
            }
        }


        while ((error_line = SR.ReadLine()) != null)
        {

            string RequiredLine2 = "Error Msg";
            // error_line = SR.ReadLine();
            if (error_line.Contains(RequiredLine2))
            {
                //crop out string that comes before:
                int index = error_line.IndexOf(":") + 1;
                error_line = error_line.Substring(index);
            }
        }
```

But it is not working.
Help please.

Comment: *What* isn't working? all your doing is reassigning a variable then doing nothing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to do it in one `while` statement, or you'll never get the error line, and you need to put the sql statement in a different parameter:

```
    string RequiredLine2 = "Error Msg";
    string RequiredLine1 = "Sql Stmt";

    while ((sql_line = SR.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (sql_line.Contains(RequiredLine1))
        {
            //crop out string that comes before:
            int index = sql_line.IndexOf(":") + 1;
            sql_stmt_line = sql_line.Substring(index);
        }

        // error_line = SR.ReadLine();
        if (error_line.Contains(RequiredLine2))
        {
            //crop out string that comes before:
            int index = error_line.IndexOf(":") + 1;
            error_line = error_line.Substring(index);
        }
    }
```

i've also put the RequiredLine2/1 outside the while statement because there is no point in creating the same string over and over again.

also, if you want  to extract more then one sql statement from the file you'll need some data structure to hold it in